# Flot Pie chart with legend & Pie labels

Tags: jquery, flot, pie-chart

I am using flot library to draw pie chart. I want to draw pie chart having combination of legend & pie labels. Wherein pie labels will only display slice percentage & corresponding label information from data series will be displayed in legend. Is this combination possible using flot charts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the slices **with percent only (no label)**, you need to define a custom `formatter` for the label option:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), datapie, { 
    series: {
         pie: {
             show: true,
             label: {
                 show: true,
                 // Added custom formatter here...
                 formatter: function(label,point){
                     return(point.percent.toFixed(2) + '%');
                 }
             }
        }
    },        
    legend: {show: true}
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JX6EJ/1/).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible, here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/Rnusy/11/

```
datapie = [
{label: "Running",  data: 19.5, color: '#e1ab0b'},
{label: "Stopped",  data: 4.5, color: '#fe0000'},
{label: "Terminated",  data: 36.6, color: '#93b40f'}
];


$.plot($("#placeholder"), datapie, {

 series: {
 pie: {show: true,
     label: {show: true}
}
},

legend: {show: true}

});
```